# How can I store data from ReactiveForms into localStorage

Tags: angular

**The problem** 
I've created an mock car dealership Angular app which displays a list of vehicles.
When you click on a vehicle you get redirected to the car detail page where you can see all the car atributes. Upon clicking the edit button on the car detail page a dialog pops up in which I need to use ReactiveForms to change vehicle data. Once the app is started, the list of cars is loaded through a .json file into localStorage. My question is how to subscribe on a ReactiveForm and instantly change car information as it's entered, save data to localStorage (update the already set data with new info on submit) and then pull data from localStorage to display as the car list. (if there is no localStorage items then pull data from .json as it was in the beggining).

[image: car details page with dialog modal and reactive form]

**form TS**

```
export class ChangeInfoFormComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EditCarComponent>) {}
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }

  carInfoForm = new FormGroup({

  brandName: new FormControl(''),
  model: new FormControl(''),
  year: new FormControl(''),
  keywords: new FormControl(''),
  })

  onSubmit() {
    // TODO: Use EventEmitter with form value
    console.warn(this.carInfoForm.value);
  }

  close() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```

**form HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="carInfoForm">
    <label for="brandName">Brand: </label>
    <input id="brandName" type="text" formControlName="brandName" (ngModel)="onSubmit();">
    <!-- <p> Value: {{brandName.value}}</p> -->
    <hr />
    <label for="model">Model: </label>
    <input id="model" type="text" formControlName="model">
    <!-- <p> Value: {{model.value}}</p> -->
    <hr />
    <label for="year">Year: </label>
    <input id="year" type="text" formControlName="year">
    <!-- <p> Value: {{year}}</p> -->
    <hr />
    <label for="keywords">Keywords: </label>
    <input id="keywords" type="text" formControlName="keywords">
    <!-- <p> Value: {{keywords.value}}</p> -->
    <br />
</form>

<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" style="margin-right: 2%;" (click)="close();">
    Back
</button>

<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" style="margin-right: 2%;" type="submit" [disabled]="!carInfoForm.valid">
    Submit
</button>
```

**car detail TS**

```
export class CarDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
  pageTitle: string = 'Car Detail';
  car: ICar | undefined;
  brand: string = '';
  model: string = '';
  sub!: Subscription;
  errorMessage: string = '';
  imageWidth: number = 400;
  imageMargin: number = 2;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private carService: CarService,
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    // private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EditCarComponent>,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const id = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
    this.pageTitle += `: `;
    // console.log('%ccar-detail.component.ts line:30 id', 'color: #007acc;', id);
    this.sub = this.carService.getCarById(id).subscribe({
      next: (cars) => {
        this.car = cars;
        console.log(this.car);
      },
      error: (err) => (this.errorMessage = err),
    });
  }

  openDialog() {
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;

    dialogConfig.data = {
      id: 1,
      title: "Test title dialogConfig",
    }

    this.dialog.open(EditCarComponent, dialogConfig);
  }

  

  onBack(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/cars']);
  }

}
```

**car detail HTML**

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        {{pageTitle + car?.brandName + ' ' + car?.model + ', ' + car?.year}}
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7 justify-content-between pt-4">
                <ul>
                    <td><b>Brand:</b> {{car?.brandName}}</td><br/>
                    <td><b>Model:</b> {{car?.model}}</td><br/>
                    <td><b>Year:</b> {{car?.year}}</td><br/>
                    <td><b>Keywords:</b> {{car?.keywords}}</td>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col justify-content-between">
                <img class="img-responsive"
                     src={{car?.imageUrl}} 
                     alt={{car?.brandName}}
                     [style.width.px]='imageWidth'
                     [style.margin.px]='imageMargin'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
                style="width: 10%; margin-right: 2%;"
                (click)="onBack()">
             Back    
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
                style="width: 10%"
                (click)="openDialog()">
            Edit
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**car list TS**

```
export class CarListComponent implements OnInit {
  pageTitle: string = 'Car List';
  imageWidth: number = 275;
  imageMargin: number = 2;
  showImage: boolean = false;
  errorMessage: string = '';
  sub!: Subscription;
  brandName: string = '';

  // listFilter: string = 'cart';
  private _listFilter: string = '';
  get listFilter(): string {
    return this._listFilter;
  }
  set listFilter(value: string) {
    this._listFilter = value;
    // console.log("In setter:", value);
    this.filteredCars = this.performFilter(value);
  }

  filteredCars: ICar[] = [];
  cars: ICar[] = [];

  constructor(private carService: CarService) {}

  performFilter(filterBy: string): ICar[] {
    filterBy = filterBy.toLocaleLowerCase();
    return this.cars.filter((car: ICar) =>
      car.brandName.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(filterBy)
    );
  }

  toggleImage(): void {
    this.showImage = !this.showImage;
  }

  showInfo(id: number): void {
    let selectedCar = this.cars.find((car) => car.carId === id);
    // console.log(selectedCar);
    this.brandName = JSON.stringify(selectedCar?.brandName);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sub = this.carService.getCars().subscribe({
      next: (cars) => {
        (this.cars = cars), (this.filteredCars = this.cars);
        // složiti funkciju za fetch i put u servisu (npr za edit forme)
        localStorage.setItem('cars', JSON.stringify(cars));
      },
      error: (err) => (this.errorMessage = err),

    });
    // default listFilter value
    // this.listFilter = "cart";
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but hell, why would you want to use localstorage for that? Did you consider State management?

Comment: because it's specified in my task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***how to subscribe on a ReactiveForm and instantly change car information as it's entered,***

You have a submit button then I dont really understand why you want to do it but you can with:

```
this.carInfoForm.valueChanges.subscribe((formValue) => { 
    console.log("formValue: ", formValue);
    // formValue.brandName
    // model.brandName
    // ...
});
```

But maybe you mean your submit button don't work, it is because you need to add the click action:

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" style="margin-right: 2%;" type="submit" [disabled]="!carInfoForm.valid" (click)="onSubmit()">
Submit
</button>
```

OR move the button inside the form tag and add ngSubmit:

```
<form [formGroup]="carInfoForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
...
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" style="margin-right: 2%;" type="submit" [disabled]="!carInfoForm.valid">
    Submit
    </button>
...
</form>
```

***save data to localStorage (update the already set data with new info on submit)***

Firstly you need to send the car ID when you open your modal:

```
dialogConfig.data = {
    id: this.getCarId(),
    title: "Test title dialogConfig",
}

getCarId(): any {
    return Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
}
```

Then retrieve the car ID inside your modal:

```
carId: any;

constructor( @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any ) {
    this.carId = data.id;
}
```

Then when you submit the form:

```
localStorage.setItem(this.carId, this.carInfoForm.value)
```

Send the form when you close the modal:

```
// TODO: bind modalRef
this.modalRef.close(this.carInfoForm.value)
```

Inside the component that open the modal add:

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open...

dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    console.log('The dialog was closed');
    this.car = result;
});
```

***and then pull data from localStorage to display as the car list. (if there is no localStorage items then pull data from .json as it was in the beggining).***

Here you should update your carService.getCarById:

```
getCarById(id: any) {
    const savedCar = localStorage.getItem(id);
    if (savedCar) {
        return savedCar;
    }
// Current code next
}
```